# TFS 2015 Destroy Files and Folders - Database grows instead of getting smaller

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have the following problem with Team Foundation Server Express 2015.
I ran out of SQL Database Space. So I cleaned up a littlebit and used TFS Destroy to permanently delete some larger files from source control.

I expected that the Size auf the table dbo.tbl_Content would get less after some time. But the opposite happened. 3000 Entries where added to the table and it got larger.

How can I cleanup TBL_Content from old files that have been destroyed already?
The TBL_Content Table has now 8.8 GB.

Executing stored procedures like prc_DeleteUnusedContent and [dbo].prc_DeleteUnusedFiles did not help at all.

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?  Having the same issues, but dealing with an 111GB content table...

Comment: What I think was a pattern was that when our team did not use the TFS for a few days then it started to clean up some of the data. @EJA: Have you destroyed the deleted files via destroy command (not just via delete comment)?

Comment: I've tried running the stored procedures, etc.  We're going to burn some of our MS support hours on this.  Trying to prep for a VSTS migration, so this needs to be resolved.

Comment: @EJA: Would be nice if you could share some of the insights you gain from MS support. Might be useful for the community. And I am really curious as well.

Answer (score 0):

Orphan data still leaves after running the tf destroy command, and will be deleted later by a TFS Background job agent. That is the reason why table dbo.tbl_Content size doesn't drops.

Here are some steps you can try to reduce the size of TFS databases:
1). Download and install [TFS2015 Power Tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) to get the Test Attachment Cleaner to remove large test attachments:

Tcmpt.exe attachmentcleanup /collection: TeamProjectCollectionUrl /teamProject: TeamProject /settingsFile: SettingsFilePath [/outputFile: ReportFilePath] [/mode: Preview/Delete]
2). Remove old workspaces which is no longer used for long time.
3). Delete old unused team projects: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181482(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that the Background job agent does not clean up the content. I deleted (using the destroy command) 300 MB about 4 days ago. That space is still not freed up.